# Why was Solomon connected to the #666

Tags: solomon

Solomon had turned away from God. He had multipled his horses, chariots & the number of his wives and concubines. How do you think Father God felt about this after the generosity the Lord had blessed him with?

Comment: Your title and question don't match up very well. Could you please [edit] either one to be clearer?

Comment: @valerie
It seems like the title and the question have little to do with each other, beyond Solomon?  Also, who connected Solomon with 666?  What was their basis for that.

Comment: _Now the weight of gold that came to Solomon in one year was six hundred threescore and six talents of gold,_ 1 Kings 10:14. This is what came _from the heathen  nations_ to Solomon.

Answer (score 3):

> Now the weight of gold that came to Solomon in one year was six hundred threescore and six talents of gold, [1 Kings 10:14 KJV].

> And the weight of the gold that hath come to Solomon in one year is six hundred sixty and six talents of gold, [Young's Literal Translation].

This is what came *to* Solomon *from the heathen nations*, as 'tribute' or taxation.

One interpretation of this is that it represents the real value of the world (the redeemed of the Lord being gathered out of the nations) coming unto Christ in his kingdom. See Revelation 21:26 (1) and Isaiah 60:11 (2).

There is no reason to suppose that the kingdom set forth in the providence of God, in Israel, is to be seen as a satanic kingdom. Rather it is to be seen as a figure of the kingdom of Jesus Christ, yet to come.

---

Solomon's *personal* fall, his heart being carried away by the abundance of what he was given in providence, in particular the women he married and had as concubines, may well have been temporary and he may well have recovered from it.

If indeed the Song of Solomon is written by Solomon then it demonstrates that, in the end, he saw what the Bride and the Bridegroom really represent and he, himself, became a part of that spirituality, despite his temporary fall.

---

> (1) And the gates of it shall not be shut at all by day: for there shall be no night there. And they shall bring the glory and honour of the nations into it. [Revelation 21:26 KJV]

> (2) Therefore thy gates shall be open continually; they shall not be shut day nor night; that men may bring unto thee the forces of the Gentiles, and that their kings may be brought. [Isaiah 60:11 KJV] See 1 Peter 2:9 'a royal priesthood'.

Comment: It may be little wonder that people reading modern translations don't see this 666 number because, e.g. the NLT reads "Each year Solomon received about 25 tons of gold." The footnote makes no mention that this equals 666 talents. But in 9:28 the footnote for him getting 16 tons of gold from Ophir does mention that this equals 420 talents. Ah, but they don't want to even have a footnote with 666 for 10:14! Makes you wonder why they have shied away from this. Your answer is significant +1

Comment: Not to be confused with the number of the beast, I assume?

Comment: @MikeBorden I assume it _is_ to be related, myself. Out of all that is subject to the Drakon and the Beast, yet comes that which is redeemed and is, as prophesied by Isaiah, gathered into the kingdom of the Christ. And it is a remarkable foresight of John's vision. proving that all scripture is given by inspiration of God, the Holy Spirit.

Comment: I don't understand the redeemed to be associated with that number.  Isn't it those who refuse to associate with the number or the name it represents  who suffer and are redeemed?

Comment: @MikeBorden Yes. They are redeemed _out of it_. We all belong to it, by nature. By redemption we are loosed from it.

Answer (score -2):

I think God felt like He was making progress in developing the character of Solomon. God gives in abundance sometimes, and I think that He gave so much to Solomon because He trusted Solomon with having much, and to also demonstrate how these blessings are not the determining factor of power or prestige. I think God was feeling like teaching Solomon about how He has everything that everyone wants already, and how easy it is to give it to a person who has been trusted by God.
The fact that Solomon was then distancing himself from God was an example of how he has a core belief that abundance in this world is relative to being same as God. But this test really is just a sad case of a man who has too much to take care of to even please God with gratitude of the gifts given to him. This is where God basically establishes a clear distinction between what God can do and what mankind cannot do. Mostly I feel like God is loving solomon enough to teach by experience and not to damn him for thinking that he is same as God. There's lots more to explore here. Great question!!!!

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).

Comment: What is the basis for saying Solomon is "thinking he is [the] same as God."
Also, it appears the answer is entirely speculation.  What are your sources?  Bible verses  are particularly helpful.